# What to do with documentation tags that are too broad and for what are they used?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-tags

When searching inside the documentation, I've found some weird and minimal tags that aren't clear for me about which language or library they are.

- [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/for-loop/topics)
- [linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/linked-list/topics)
- [boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/boolean/topics)

For what are they? Isn't is better to delete these tags on documentation? In my opinion, it isn't clear what languages there are used and so a bit to broad to make a documentation tag about that.

Comment: I would say all those should be removed completely.

Comment: What the heck are these *"Installation or Setup"* examples and why has one of it an upvote? Setup a boolean oO?

Comment: For the same reason most of the other not useful examples are upvoted.

Comment: I wonder how these got created. Maybe they should require a bronze or silver badge in a tag (rather than 150 rep and 1 positively scored answer) in order to commit to the associated Documentation tag. Is there an established Documentation burnination process yet?

Comment: And unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be *any* way to flag a topic for review.

Comment: Remove them from the site, that way they are removed by proxy.